# regex to parse first line of stack trace

Tags: regex, splunk

Below is the sample text

4 different stacktrace events(EROR events) with different time stamps(time stamp is not mentioned here).
first two events are just single lines but next two error events are multilines my regex

(?PERROR\s-\s[a-zA-Z0-9+\s.\:()\,-\=>_]+)

is currently matching everything i.e two single line events and two multiline events(all the lines)

```
ERROR - An Error has occured for com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Your session has timed out.
ERROR - An Error has occured for com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Record has been modified since last retrieved - Resubmit transaction
ERROR - handleException():com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Your session has timed out.
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.prepareUserContext(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.preexecute(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.execute(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java(Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminaters(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager"
ERROR - handleException():com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Record has been modified since last retrieved - Resubmit transaction
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.ServiceAgreementImpl.updateAgreement(ServiceAgreementImpl.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreementmgmt.CSAManagerImpl.updateCSA(CSAManagerImpl.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreementmgmt.ejb.EJSRemoteStatelessServiceagreementManager_3dcfd156.updateCSA(Unknown Source)
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreementmgmt.ejb._ServiceagreementManagerRemote_Stub.updateCSA(_ServiceagreementManagerRemote_Stub.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.proxy.CSAProxy.updateCSA(CSAProxy.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.SaveCSAAction.performAction(SaveCSAAction.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.execute(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java(Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminaters(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager"
```

I want result like below just one line for each event

```
ERROR - An Error has occured for com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Your session has timed out.
ERROR - An Error has occured for com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Record has been modified since last retrieved - Resubmit transaction
ERROR - handleException():com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Your session has timed out.
ERROR - handleException():com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Record has been modified since last retrieved - Resubmit transaction
```

Any help on improving my regex to match result like above?

EDIT :

With current regex (?PERROR\s-\s[^\n\r]+) it matching below line

```
ERROR - handleException():com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Remote Exception while updating CSA Details for CSA id 1463755 and Account id 11242
```

I wanted to match

```
ERROR - handleException():com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Remote Exception while updating CSA Details for CSA id
```

i.e to without numbers so i used (?PERROR\s-\s[^\n\r]+?(?=[0-9])) but it loosing all other previous matches, only matching above line

EDIT:

```
ERROR - handleException():com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Error  in agreement  update Record has been modified since last retrieved - Resubmit transaction
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.ServiceAgreementImpl.updateAgreement(ServiceAgreementImpl.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreementmgmt.CSAManagerImpl.updateCSA(CSAManagerImpl.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreementmgmt.ejb.EJSRemoteStatelessServiceagreementManager_3dcfd156.updateCSA(Unknown Source)
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreementmgmt.ejb._ServiceagreementManagerRemote_Stub.updateCSA(_ServiceagreementManagerRemote_Stub.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.proxy.CSAProxy.updateCSA(CSAProxy.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.SaveCSAAction.performAction(SaveCSAAction.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.execute(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java(Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java(Compiled Code))

ERROR - An Error has occured for com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Error  in agreement  update Record has been modified since last retrieved - Resubmit transaction
ERROR - handleException():com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Your session has timed out.
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.prepareUserContext(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.preexecute(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.execute(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java(Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminaters(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java(Compiled Code))"
 ERROR - handleException():com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Record has been modified since last retrieved - Resubmit transaction
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.ServiceAgreementImpl.updateAgreement(ServiceAgreementImpl.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreementmgmt.CSAManagerImpl.updateCSA(CSAManagerImpl.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreementmgmt.ejb.EJSRemoteStatelessServiceagreementManager_3dcfd156.updateCSA(Unknown Source)
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreementmgmt.ejb._ServiceagreementManagerRemote_Stub.updateCSA(_ServiceagreementManagerRemote_Stub.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.proxy.CSAProxy.updateCSA(CSAProxy.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.SaveCSAAction.performAction(SaveCSAAction.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.execute(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java(Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminaters(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java(Compiled Code))
  ERROR - handleException():com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Error  in product  update Error from px_co_ac_agreement_product_pg.spt_add==>ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.ServiceAgreementImpl.updateAgreement(ServiceAgreementImpl.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreementmgmt.CSAManagerImpl.updateCSA(CSAManagerImpl.java:204)
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreementmgmt.ejb.EJSRemoteStatelessServiceagreementManager_3dcfd156.updateCSA(Unknown Source)
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreementmgmt.ejb._ServiceagreementManagerRemote_Stub.updateCSA(_ServiceagreementManagerRemote_Stub.java:481)
at com.marsh.csa.proxy.CSAProxy.updateCSA(CSAProxy.java:178)
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.SaveCSAAction.performAction(SaveCSAAction.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.execute(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java(Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminaters(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java(Compiled Code))
   ERROR - Remote Exception while updating CSA Details java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.RemoteException: ; nested exception is: 
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex pattern contains `\s`, which match all white space characters, including `\n` and/or `\r`, which causes your problem...

Replace a content of your character set `[...]` with `^\n\r`, to match any characters in such line, but not allow to go beyond the end of line:

```
(?PERROR\s-\s[^\n\r]+)
```

---

#### EDIT:

Based on OP's update and other facts discussed in chat, the following regex pattern has been suggested:

```
(?PERROR\s-\s[^\n\r]*?(?=[^\S\n\r]*\d{7}|[^\S\n\r]*[\n\r]|[^\S\n\r]*$))
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42406/discussion-between-pradi-and-mega-)

Comment: @Pradi - I have updated my answer above. Please remove all your above comments, except the one that says "let us continue this discussion in chat", so this post is clean. You may consider to delete also you other comments from other answers, so this question stays clean for other visitors. I will come later to delete also this comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying the regex engine you use.
On [RegEx101](http://regex101.com/) (with *perl-compatible* engine, and also with *python* engine) your regex doesn't match at all.

Use:

```
ERROR - .*
```

*without multiline* flag.

It will match till the end of the line.

**EDIT:**

The above regex means:

- `ERROR -` matches the characters `ERROR -` literally (case sensitive)
- `.*` matches any character (except newline) zero or more times

Comment: This one also works but looks simple. can you explain me the meaning of above regex.

Comment: Also can you tell me how to end the matching like at particular word or period/fullstop or space. e.g in above sample text matching should end before the "at" word.

Comment: See my edit about regex meaning. To match till "at", you can use this one `ERROR - (\w| (?!at ))*`, see it live at http://regex101.com/r/vJ0tP7

Answer (score 0):

You could try matching explicitly non-newline characters after the "ERROR - " piece (untested):

```
(?PERROR\s-\s[^\n]+)
```

I think it's the fact that you have \s in your match space.

Comment: Thanks for answer but it's not working without \r in character set